# How to check for undefined in reactjs mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a app which fetches data using `axios` after that it stores this it in redux store. Everything works fine if data is available from the api endpoint but the problem arise when i am getting no data it gives me error saying this.

> TypeError: props.teamProduct._embedded is undefined
>
> This is how my data looks on successfull call

[image: successfull]

> when i get undefined result

[image: undefined]

> Here is my code

This is how I am getting `team` list from store

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    
    team: state.productDetails.team.team.data,
  };
};
```

After that i m passing this to component

> productDetail

```
{teamProduct &&
              teamProduct._embedded.cartResourceList.map((item, index) => {
                console.log("item", item);
                if (index < 2) {
                  return (
                    <Grid
                      key={index}
                      container
                      item
                      xs={12}
                      className="mid_box"
                    >
                      <Grid container item xs={6}>
                      
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  );
                }
              })}
```

Is there any way to check for undefined value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check all property accesses to the one you actually need

```
{teamProduct && 
  teamProduct._embedded &&
  teamProduct._embedded.cartResourceList &&
  teamProduct._embedded.cartResourceList.map((item, index) => {
    console.log("item", item);
    if (index < 2) {
      return (
        <Grid
          key={index}
          container
          item
          xs={12}
          className="mid_box"
        >
          <Grid container item xs={6}></Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  })
}
```